# Is it possible in Hazelcast (client-server model) to indicate the service to build the cache?

Tags: caching, microservices, hazelcast, distributed-caching, hazelcast-cloud

I have 2 microservices in spring boot (let's say microservice A and B) and client-server Hazelcast. There is some cache-building logic in microservice A and I want to use the same cache in microservice B. I know we can get the Map and use it. But what if there is a cache miss? is there any way to indicate the microservice A to build the cache and then return it to microservice B? If it's not possible, can we do something after we ship the cache-building logic to cache server? I don't want to have the same cache-building logic in multiple services.

Answer (score 0):

One option here might be a [MapLoader](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/ingest/overview#when-to-use-a-maploadermapstore)

When a map is first accessed (and so empty) map loader logic can be attached to populate it.

You can choose to load all content at once, per key on a cache miss, or a combination of the two.